# How to create composite .cs file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I need to create one .cs file from all .cs files of the solution(Visual Studio 2012) for some bureaucracy. Is there a plugin that can help me with it?

Comment: My answer explains why this isn't feasible. If you can give more background to why you think you need to do this, we might be able to help you find alternatives.

Comment: Agree with @JonSkeet. If you need this for not for compile purpose but for "human audit" purpose (even if I doubt it could be useful or rational...), you could probably get it with a simple batch file.

Answer (score 7):

That isn't possible, in a general sense. Consider these two files:

Foo.cs:

```
#define X

#if Y
#error Bang!
#endif

#if !X
#error Bang!
#endif

class Foo {}
```

Bar.cs:

```
#define Y

#if X
#error Bang!
#endif

#if !Y
#error Bang!
#endif

class Bar {}
```

Note that `#define` and `#undef` have to come at the start of a C# file... so the whole file is processed with the same set of symbols defined - but your original two files were processed with *different* sets of symbols defined.

I would strongly advise you to try to remove the requirement.